# Why was my neural networks question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I don't make the mistake repeatedly, and I would like to know why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728359/why-is-my-1-hidden-layer-neural-network-with-relus-not-getting-more-that-18-acc) was downvoted.

I was careful to read the Stack Overflow rules beforehand and make sure to add an MVCE to the question. A machine learning example is not complete without a dataset, so the code was little long, but I felt it was better than posting code that was not complete.

Please do not just downvote this question also. I really am trying to get better. I just don't understand what I'm supposed to do differently next time if all I see is a downvote. People seem to downvote for arbitrary reasons even after I spend hours researching and preparing an MCVE.

Comment: Preemptive note: downvotes and upvotes here on Meta do not affect reputation.

Comment: I'm truthfully a little baffled by that, too; it seems like a reasonable question to me because you're asking about a specific problem (the fact that you're only getting 18% accuracy when you expected to get 90% accuracy with that method) with specific code. It looks to me like whoever downvoted/close voted just got it wrong.

Comment: or, the sky was blue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It has a single -1. Don't worry about it. Really.
People don't have to (and should not have to) justify their downvotes -- not even to themself.

I know it is hard at low rep to do this, **but votes are a very noisy process.**
Don't read too much into it.

Possible reasons:

- your MWE is *huge*

  - Sure, it requires a lot to be able to verify it completely -- but we don't want to on stackoverflow do that so often (unlike if you say made an issue report on github.). There are pros and cons as to if including the stuff to do with loading the data.
  - In particular you even include fancy functions to display progress indicators -- that is not minimal. And line after line of extracting code, all with loverly error messages. Not minimal.
  - Your actual code that matters is like <30% of what you have shown.
  - If you do want to include all this data loading stuff (which as I said, has pros and cons), then at very least have a separate code box for the actual code you are interested in. (i.e. the stuff where you declare your network.)
- Your question is thus very long. (Which makes it seem bad, who wants to read that much?)
- You've answered it, your network is overfitting, that is clear, well done. What can an answer even tell you now?

  - Asking about how to avoid overfitting is a better question to be
    separated away from code entirely.

But people also can and do vote for arbitrary reasons:

- It would not be unhead of for someone to -1 you for ending a post with "thankyou"

  - [we don't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/144630).
  - normal process is to edit it out; but someone could decide to downvote for it.
- You used asking for "opinion" phrase: "what do you think I'm doing wrong here?"

  - Some would prefer that things are written in a non-personal way, eg "What is incorrect with the implementation above."
- They could have outright accidentally clicked -1 instead of +1. Given the tens of millions of questions on the site, that must have happened hundreds of times.

Comment: It's just confusing because I've had questions downvoted in the past because I only posted the part of the code that I thought mattered and didn't post an MCVE. So now I try to post an MCVE and it's too much code.

Comment: @MatthewDrill: Well, it has to be complete *and* minimal. It's not "Minimal/Complete/Verifiable Example (pick any two)", after all.

Comment: Matthew Drill: As I said it is a very noisy process. Don't over analyze it. 
It is a vote from just 1 person and reflects only *their* opinion.